# Check php -V Showing Error

Tags: php

error shown below

```
php: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.2: version `OPENSSL_1.0.2d' not found (required by php)
php: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.2: version `OPENSSL_1.0.2d' not found (required by php)
```

Comment: What Linux distribution and which version are you using. Do you have `openssl` package installed?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Linux Distribution : 16.04  and we are not using openssl

Comment: Comment out `libsssl.so` and `libcrtypto.so` in `php.ini`